# My Pokémon game keeps auto-resetting

Tags: pokemon-third-generation

I was playing *Pokemon Sapphire*, and I encountered a glitch of some sort. While I was in the middle of a Pokemon battle, my *GBA SP* decided to randomly automatically restart.

At first, I thought it may have been due to an old system, however it continued repeatedly. I switched the game into a *DS Lite*, and that did not fix anything.

I was able to figure out that the auto-reset only occurred when I switched out to specific Pokemon, *Gardevoir* for example. Has anybody else encountered this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be some sort of glitch in the cartridge or the Gardevoir. In one of my games, Pokemon Platinum, which I bought new, the screen would make a little black streak when using an HM move. even after restarting the game, this would still happen.

I would recommend trading all of your Pokemon to another game and restarting Sapphire. See if Gardevoir affects your other games if you do this.

I have never ran into this issue. It may also be the internal battery, but I cannot be positive. These are all suggestions, so I cannot guarantee they will work. Good luck and be sure to catch 'em all!

Comment: Sadly, I am unable to trade the the Gardevoir, as there is not another system to trade with, and I'm certain it isn't the internal battery, as I do not get the "internal battery" message. However, I will agree on it may be a glitch in the cartridge or the Pokemon itself.

Comment: @Wondercricket that is quite unfortunate. My condolences.